# How to obtain page number from html web address

Tags: php, html, url, url-rewriting, get

I'm trying to get page number from web address like `beds.html?page=3`

but, if I use php `get` method, then it's not returning anything.

I hope to find any easy solution.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If You Want that parameter on html page then you have to use javascript for it**

```
<script>
    var param1var = getQueryVariable("page");

    function getQueryVariable(variable) {
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
          return pair[1];
        }
      } 
      alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
    }
    </script>
```

**if you are on php page simply use**

```
<?php 
 echo  $_GET['page']; 
?>
```

Comment: hi, how to print out or save in php variables. cheers

Comment: echo $variable_name = $_GET['page'];   ///to store value in php variable

Answer (score 0):

you can get page like this:

```
<?php 
$_REQUEST['page']; 
?>
```

and also you can type `echo` before $|_REQUEST to check you are getting proper page number or not

Comment: cheers mate, but get and request method is not working. i have use mode_rewrite to generate html pages ( not php ) it is .html

Comment: why you used php tag?

Comment: cos i am doing this for friendly url and html should do a good job.

Answer (score 0):

get is the right method to use.

```
<?php 
  $_GET['page']; 
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget about XSS attacks. Check the value of $_GET['page'].

Comment: cheers mate, but get and request method is not working. i have use mode_rewrite to generate html pages ( not php ) it is .html